# CTRL-C out of async

Tags: python-3.x

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the following program does NOT `break` and `exit`. What is the correct way to enable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

```
import sys

import asyncio
import datetime
import functools

import logging

from tastyworks.streamer import DataStreamer
from tastyworks.tastyworks_api import tasty_session
from tastyworks.models.session import TastyAPISession

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


async def main_loop(session: TastyAPISession, streamer: DataStreamer):
    # sub_values = {
    #     "Greeks": [
    #         ".VIX180718C21",
    #         ".YUM180518C95"
    #     ]
    # }
    sub_values = {
        "Quote": ["/ES"]
    }

    # get all active orders
    orders = await session.get_active_orders()
    LOGGER.info('Number of active orders: %s', len(orders))

    # set up some streamers
    await streamer.add_data_sub(sub_values)

    async for item in streamer.listen():
        LOGGER.info('Received item: %s' % item.data)


def main():

    tasty_client = tasty_session.create_new_session('uname', 'pwd')

    streamer = DataStreamer(tasty_client)
    LOGGER.info('Streamer token: %s' % streamer.get_streamer_token())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main_loop(tasty_client, streamer))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Received exit, exiting")
    finally:
        # find all futures/tasks still running and wait for them to finish
        pending_tasks = [
            task for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks() if not task.done()
        ]
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*pending_tasks))
        loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When keyboardInterrupt Exception starts by default it stops the script. In your script you replaced the keyboardInterrupt exception to your code which it doesn't stop the script.

to solve that problem you need to add `exit()` on the exception

here is your code:

```
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main_loop(tasty_client, streamer))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Received exit, exiting")
finally:
    # find all futures/tasks still running and wait for them to finish
    pending_tasks = [
        task for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks() if not task.done()
    ]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*pending_tasks))
    loop.close()
```

here is the Solve:

```
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main_loop(tasty_client, streamer))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Received exit, exiting")
    # find all futures/tasks still running and wait for them to finish
    pending_tasks = [
        task for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks() if not task.done()
    ]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*pending_tasks))
    loop.close()
    exit()#stops the script
```

Comment: Correction, I do see, "Received exit, exiting", but the program does not go back to the command prompt. I suspect it is the finally block that is the culprit...

Comment: yep that works. I takes  a while to stop the program though. The finally block version might also work, I may just need more patience in letting it find the pending_tasks...